# Show that this operator is identity operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let a vector space  $W=$ span of $\{v_1,v_2 ,\cdots,v_a\}$. 
Let a operator $(M^{(a)})_{i, j}=\sum_{t=1}^a(v_t)_i(v_t)_j$
Show that this operator is identity?

I can show that when $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_a\}$ are linearly independent.  If they are not linearly independent how will show that it is an identity operator

Answer (score 1):

Assume the vectors $v_k$ are *orthonormal*, this means that

$$
v_t \cdot v_k = \sum_{j}v_t^j v_k^j = \delta_{tk} \tag{1}
$$

where $v_t^i$ means the $i$-th component of the vector $v_t$ in the basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^a$,

$$
v_t = \sum_kv_t^i e_i \tag{2}
$$

Consider an arbitrary vector $x$

$$
x = \sum_k c_k v_k \stackrel{(2)}{=} \sum_{kj}c_k v_k^je_j \tag{3} \equiv \sum_j x_j e_j, ~~~\mbox{with}~~~ x_j = \sum_k c_k v_k^j
$$

Such that the $i$-th component of the product $M^{(a)}x$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
[M^{(a)}x]_i &=& \sum_j M^{(a)}_{ij}x_j \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=}& \sum_{jtk} v_t^iv_t^j c_kv_k^j = \sum_{tk}c_kv_t^i\left(\sum_j v_t^j v_k^j\right) \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \sum_{tk} c_k v_t^i\delta_{tk} = \sum_k c_k v_k^i \\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}& x_i \tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

From this you can conclude that

$$
M^{a}x = x
$$

for any $x$, that is $M^a$ is the identity matrix!